# ASP.NET MVC - Model binding multiple parameters with same name in different entities - GET and POST different?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was taking advantage of model binding to populate a particular parameter name in 3 separate places within an action method signature (2 filter entity parameters and a normal controller action parameter).

i.e.

```
public ViewResult foo(Entity1 something, Entity2 somethingelse, somefield)
```

where Entity1 and Entity2 both have somefield within them.

For one request I tested using GET and everything worked fine. For another request I used POST and only the parameter by the exact same name in the action method was populated. The rest of the parameters in the entities were mapped correctly. I tested it with another parameter, and found the same results.

Does ASP.NET MVC only populate one parameter by a particular name for POST requests, but multiple instances of a parameter by a particular parameter name for GET requests? Is this "undefined" behavior and a misuse of the model binder?

Comment: How do you have your route setup so this works as you want for your GET request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am quite sure something else is amiss. I just gave it a test with the following

```
public class Foo
{  
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{  
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and as controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Foo bar, Bar foo, string Name)
{

    return View();
}
```

and for the view just a simple

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home")) { 

    @Html.TextBox("Name")

    <input type="submit" value="save" />
}
```

and it works as expected, both `bar.Name`, `foo.Name`, and `Name` itself are filled with the value supplied when submitting.

So no difference between POST and GET.

To even go further into detail, this is what MVC does, where *MethodInfo* is an object of type `System.Reflection.MethodInfo`, which represents the action method about to be executed:

```
ParameterInfo[] parameterInfos = MethodInfo.GetParameters();
var rawParameterValues = 
        from parameterInfo in parameterInfos
        select ExtractParameterFromDictionary(parameterInfo, parameters, MethodInfo);
```

So for each parameter defined for the given method it will try to retrieve the parameter values from object `parameters` which is, amongst others, what is supplied by the querystring.